# How to build DOM tree from XML file by ourself, i.e. don't use DocumentBuilder.parse(xml)?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

Suppose there is a simple XML file as below:

```
<a>
    <b>hello</b>
    <c>world</c>
</a>
```

I want to create a DOM tree, without using the parser provided by Java library ( I do want to use other APIs and data structures, like Element). I am kind of familiar with the lexing(tokenization) part, but how to use the tokens to build the tree ?

The tree creating algorithm is something I learnt from data structure classes. The problem is how to utilize the given DOM framework in Java library? like **Element**, or **Node**, or **DOM APIs** which can help insert new nodes to the DOM tree.

Is there any exiting examples that I can learn from ?

Comment: Not a real question. Or rather, there is too much. This is asking "How can I write an XML parser?" You just do. Or use a library that does. Or use parts of a library that does .. there is the [W3C DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) package standard in the [Java 6 XML-related APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/xml/index.html). YMMV.

Comment: Just to be clear. Do you want to learn how to create dom tree using apis .. or do you don't care about xml programming  and just want to create XML using some apis. If it is the latter you are you care you can use JAXP framework and generate an XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start off from [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html), create a `DocumentBuilder` and from this create a new `Document` object.  From there, `Document` has methods to add elements, attributes, etc so you can use these methods to generate a document.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
//dbf.setNamespaceAware(true); //If you need namespace support turn this on, it is off by default

Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();

//Add a root element
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Attr att = doc.createAttribute("my-attribute");
att.setValue("value");
rootElement.appendChild(att);
```